# Angular2 with spring boot LDAP authentication

Tags: angular, authentication, spring-security, spring-security-ldap

I created login page in Angular 2 and want to use ldap authentication at the spring boot service layer. i am very new to this concept. I had written the code but i am not sure whether my code at service layer is getting called or not. When i run the application i am getting "could not authenticate" and no error or log statements at the console.Can you please take a look at it and provide your suggestions ?

```
login.component.ts
----------------------
login(username:string , password:string) {
 if(username != '' && password != ''){
 if(!username.endsWith('@abc.com')){
            username += '@abc.com';
          }

this.loading = true;
 this.authService.login(username, password)
           .subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.router.navigate(['./jobcleanup/home']);
                },
                error => {

                   alert("could not authenticate");
                    this.loading = false;
                });
}
```

### auth.service.ts

```
login(username: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
    alert('inside authservice login');
      let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
       let body = {"username": username, "password": password};
        return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/login', body ,options)
            .map((response: Response) => {
                let token = response.json() && response.json().token;
                if (token) {
                    this.token = token;
                       localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ username: username, token: token }));
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Service Layer

```
Rest Controller



@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String loginForm(Model model){
        logger.info("Login Form");
        return "login";

    }
AuthConfig
-----------------

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login*").anonymous()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }


 @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider()).userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    }

    @Override
    protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return userDetailsService;
    }


    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
        return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider()));
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {

        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("abc.com", "ldap://ldap.abc.com:389");
        provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
        provider.setUserDetailsContextMapper(userDetailsContextMapper);
        return provider;
    }
```

Comment: change you logging in  `error => { console.log(error); } `, you don't need an alert, so at least you know what error it is, also check your server logs.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding XSRFStrategy in Angular main **app.module.ts**

```
export function xsrfFactory() { return new CookieXSRFStrategy('XSRF-TOKEN', 'x-xsrf-token'); }


...
providers : [
  { provide: XSRFStrategy, useFactory: xsrfFactory },
]
```

this should add the header to your http calls.

Then your change **Spring configuration** like this

```
 @Override
    protected void configureHttpSecurity(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

   http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).ignoringAntMatchers("/login/**");    

    // @formatter:off
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated() // your rest api here
        .antMatchers("/login/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
    // @formatter:on

    http.logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/");

}


    @Bean
    public CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
        CookieCsrfTokenRepository repository = new CookieCsrfTokenRepository();
        repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
        repository.setCookieHttpOnly(false);
        return repository;
    }
```

Hopefully it works.

By the way I'd suggest testing your security config in Spring with an **integration test first**, try something  like this

```
@Test
public void testWebApplicationContext_httpSecurityUnathorisedAccess_exceptionHandling() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/info").contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)).andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
}

@Test
@WithMockUser(username = "user.something", authorities = { "view"})
public void testWebApplicationContext_httpSecurityAuthorisedAccess_ok() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/info").contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)).andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(model().attributeExists("username")).andExpect(view().name("info"));
}
```